# Drill down solidgauge chart to 2 series bar chart

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I need to add SolidGauge - HighCharts with drilldown.
I couldn't add drilldown for gauge. So I ve tried to load the div by calling script function

```
<div id="YTDSolidGauge" onload="drawGaugeChart();" onclick="drawBarChart(this);" ></div>

<div id="YTDBar" onclick="drawGaugeChart();"></div>
```

And trigger function in the barchart's function,

```
events:{ 
       click: function(){
            alert('test');
            drawGaugeChart();
        }
    }
```

When I wrote the onload function in the gauge, the chart has disappeared.
I want the gauge to be loaded first and when we click on it, bar should be loaded.
When we click on the bar chart, it should be back to the gauge.
or we can reload the particular div to load another div.
I have a lot of charts, so it's better to call by function instead of writing 'onload' function in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch click event in the [series.point.events](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events), destroy chart and create new one (bar). Then add also click event and call destroy/init.

```
var barOptions,
        solidOptions;

barOptions = {
    chart:{
    type: 'bar'
  },
  series:[{
    data:[1,2,3]
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            var chart = this.series.chart;

            chart.destroy();

            Highcharts.chart('container', solidOptions);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

}

solidOptions = {
 chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  pane: {
    center: ['50%', '85%'],
    size: '140%',
    startAngle: -90,
    endAngle: 90,
    background: {
      backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
      innerRadius: '60%',
      outerRadius: '100%',
      shape: 'arc'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            var chart = this.series.chart;

            chart.destroy();

            Highcharts.chart('container', barOptions);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      y: 56.33,
    }]
  }]
};


Highcharts.chart('container', solidOptions);
```

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/nxaLpnLz/